# how can I print the return value of a function to entry in tinker?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def c_to_f(celsius):
    return str(float(celsius) * 1.8 + 32)

window = Tk()
f = Label(window, text="ºF")
f.pack()

finpt = Entry(window)
fvalue = finpt.get()
finpt.pack()

c = Label(window, text="ºC")
c.pack()

cinpt = Entry(window)
cvalue = cinpt.get()
cinpt.pack()

to_f = Button(window, text="Nach ºF umrechnen", command=finpt.insert(0, f"{c_to_f(cvalue)}"))
to_f.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

After pressing the button, I want to return the show the result of `c_to_f(cvalue)` in Label `c`. How can I manage that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to create another function for the button `to_f` and do the conversion and show result inside that function:

```py
from tkinter import *

def c_to_f(celsius):
    return str(float(celsius) * 1.8 + 32)

def convert_to_fahrenheit():
    try:
        f = c_to_f(cinpt.get())
        finpt.delete(0, END)
        finpt.insert(END, f)
    except ValueError as ex:
        print(ex)

window = Tk()

f = Label(window, text="ºF")
f.pack()

finpt = Entry(window)
#fvalue = finpt.get()
finpt.pack()

c = Label(window, text="ºC")
c.pack()

cinpt = Entry(window)
#cvalue = cinpt.get()
cinpt.pack()

to_f = Button(window, text="Nach ºF umrechnen", command=convert_to_fahrenheit)
to_f.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is giving too much problem.

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
 

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Temperature Converter')
root.geometry('300x70')
root.resizable(False, False)


def fahrenheit_to_celsius(f):
    """ Convert fahrenheit to celsius
    """
    return (f - 32) * 5/9

frame = ttk.Frame(root)

options = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}

temperature_label = ttk.Label(frame, text='Fahrenheit')
temperature_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='W', **options)

temperature = tk.StringVar()
temperature_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=temperature)
temperature_entry.grid(column=1, row=0, **options)
temperature_entry.focus()


def convert_button_clicked():
    f = float(temperature.get())
    c = fahrenheit_to_celsius(f)
    result = f'{f} Fahrenheit = {c:.2f} Celsius'
    result_label.config(text=result)
     
convert_button = ttk.Button(frame, text='Convert')
convert_button.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky='W', **options)
convert_button.configure(command=convert_button_clicked)

result_label = ttk.Label(frame)
result_label.grid(row=1, columnspan=3, **options)

frame.grid(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You can modified code to suit.